# How this IPs goes throught my htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ip, spam, mybb

I have htaccess file like this:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
...doesn't matter....some ips...
deny from all
</Limit>
```

And this ip adressess in MYBB:

```
5.10.83.26
5.10.83.7
5.10.83.40
```

every day making my server overloaded, and than it is stucked, I have to wait for host to flush-hosts, I haven't permission...

How those ip adresses avoiding my restrictions in htaccess? -Yes, I am sure they are not allowed.

I use WordPress as root, and subfolder is MyBB. Those adresses I see in MyBB.

At least how can I add deny from 5.10.83.00/26 to htaccess and keep deny from all.

Comment: Do you know it's Apache that is overloaded and not some other process?

Comment: I don't know. I can't tell anything, right now, I take my site offline, 'till I find the solution. I saw my site loading slower some minutes ago, I checked mybb "who is online", and bunch of this ips were on differents topics/forums.

Comment: If this is an important site, you may need professional help.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you how there getting through your restrictions, but according to [this whois result for 5.10.83.*](http://en.utrace.de/whois/5.10.83.26) the people to ask can be reached at 'abuse@softlayer.com'

Softlayer is a cloud platform and whoever is causing your DOS is one of there clients ... good luck

Comment: I read now on google that it is easily for bad guys to avoid htaccess, and for real protection I should use firewall on my site. But, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: can't offer you any advice on the firewall, specially since we don't even know what sort of os and configuration your being hosted on but I would definitely report the problem to softlayer (make sure you include times with the ip addresses so they can get a fix on the culprit)